# White bar glitch with many alpha images

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

White bar appears when I add many alpha images on top of each other.
[image]

If I remove one element it will disappear, and if I add it appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation in flash. Try to limit your use of alpha if possible Overlapping alpha is expensive.

It looks like you might be building some kind of face builder? If you can't reduce your use of alphas, perhaps you could collapse your alpha layers into a smaller number of bitmaps by manipulating the bitmapdata and copying multiple layers into a single bitmap object.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a redraw artifact.  One way to fix this is to make a movieclip out of a vector shape.  Then scale the movieclip to be larger than your fla's stage by at least about 20 pixels on each side.  Now turn that movieclip into another movieclip so you have a movieclip inside a movieclip.  Turn the fill color of the inner movieclip to alpha 0.  Now animate the inner movieclip with a tween, back and forth about 5 pixels, endlessly looping.  Inside the outer movieclip, on its first frame, add:

```
this.mouseChildren = false;
this.mouseEnabled = false;
```

That way the movieclip won't block any mouse interactions.  Let this movieclip run constantly.  It will wipe any artifacts away by forcing a redraw on every frame.